# Best approach for loading settings that can be modified in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Hello all fellow StackOverFlow'ers,

I'm making an app in Flask that runs depending on settings that can be changed by administrator via a `POST request` in their admin-panel,

Actually, the only two things I came up with for doing this is using `os.environ.get` (**Environment variables**) [which i'm using now] or insert it to a *`PostreSQL`* Database config table and load it up

Anyway I will be storing settings such as a couple of **API_URLs** and their **API_KEY**, and some Conditions of checking like a success value where `if condition in text .. else` is applied to ... where admin can change them via the panel

I'm looking for the best performant approach for doing such thing.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the changes to only apply on a per-user basis (changes made by the admin only affect the admin), check out Flask's [sessions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.session). It works like a dictionary, but stores information in a cookie in the user's browser that can be programmatically accessed by Flask. **Be warned that this data is stored in plain-text in the user's browser, so don't store anything sensitive here.**

On the other hand, if you're looking for changes made by the admin to affect everybody visiting the website, you may just be able to store the settings in a variable, update them when the admin makes changes, and read them when responding to a request. If you want these settings to persist through a server restart, however, you'll need to write them to disk and then load them on server restart and save them to disk when they're changed. If this is a production-grade app and needs to be able to scale, I personally recommend using an SQLite file to store settings (or a SQL database if it *really* needs to scale), but this is a personal preference of mine. If this is just a personal app, storing settings in text files would be just fine.

Hope this helps!